# C++, Linux: error: conversion from ‘boost::unique_future<void>’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::shared_future<void>’ requested. how to get around it?

Tags: c++, boost, scheduled-tasks, boost-thread, future

I try to work with [boost thread futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures). So as shown [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Reviews-Futures-packaged-task-and-shared-future-td2653185.html) we can get [shared future](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.shared_future) from [packaged task](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.packaged_task).

So I try such function on linux:

```
template <class task_return_t>
void pool_item( boost::shared_ptr< boost::packaged_task<task_return_t> > pt)
{
    boost::shared_future<task_return_t> fi= pt->get_future(); // error
    //...
```

but I get error calling it:

```
../../src/cf-util/thread_pool.h: In member function ‘void thread_pool::pool_item(boost::shared_ptr<boost::packaged_task<R> >) [with task_return_t = void]’:
../../src/cf-util/thread_pool.h:64:3:   instantiated from ‘void thread_pool::post(boost::shared_ptr<boost::packaged_task<R> >) [with task_return_t = void]’
../../src/cf-server/server.cpp:39:27:   instantiated from here
../../src/cf-util/thread_pool.h:124:58: error: conversion from ‘boost::unique_future<void>’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::shared_future<void>’ requested
```

I did not take any futures from that task before. [all source code](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/), [place where I do call from](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/cf-server/server.cpp?r=1477), [my thread pool that is being called](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/cf-util/thread_pool.h?r=1477). And on Windows under Visual Studio 2010 it compiles and works perfectly.

What shall I do? how to fix or get around this error?

Comment: Perhaps a version problem? I can convert a `unique_future` to a `shared_future` just fine on my end.

Comment: @Luc Danton: Show me how and I will try it!) Secondly problem is I pass tasks to my task manager that than sends tham into this function. So problem here is that `unique_future` can be already taken\assigned and be on `.wait();` for example.

Comment: Like you're attempting: `boost::shared_future<int> f = task.get_future();` where `task` is `boost::packaged_task<int> task;`. (Your second problem sounds like it warrants a separate question.)

Answer (score 4):

The conversion from `unique_future` to `shared_future` uses the following constructor in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.shared_future):

```
shared_future(unique_future<R> && other);
```

This uses an rvalue reference to ensure that it's clear in the source code that you intended to destroy the value of 'other'. It's possible that VC++2010 provides enough rvalue reference support by default to support that directly, while the compiler you're using on linux (probably gcc) requires an extra flag like `-std=gnu++0x` to support it. Without that flag, boost falls back to "move emulation", which might (I haven't checked this) require you to write:

```
boost::shared_future<task_return_t> fi = boost::move(pt->get_future());
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeffrey Yasskin is correct. The function compiles with g++ (4.6.3) on Linux with the -std=gnu++0x flag, or with the -std=c++0x flag if you want strictly ISO compilation. These -std flags are now deprecated in favour of gnu++11 and c++11 respectively. (I'd have just made this a comment but don't yet have sufficient privelege)

Comment: -std=gnu++11 is only supported with gcc-4.7 and above and clang-3.0 or -3.1 and above, so I haven't decided whether I prefer code to use it or the "0x" spelling.  In the long run, yes, the "11" spelling will be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you forgot to include the right headers?

If not, does a different constructor like the one below work?

```
boost::shared_future<task_return_t> fi(pt->get_future());
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you should call std::future::share() to obtain a shared_future from a future. E.g.,

```
auto sf=std::async([]{/* something */}).share();
```